# Vue JS - How to wrap every second element in a block using a for loop

Tags: javascript, vue.js, for-loop, vuejs2

I have four ordinary images that I display using the foor loop, I need to make every second image wrapped inside a div.

That is, I want to get the following result

```
  <div>
    <div>
      <img src="" alt="img">
      <img src="" alt="img">
    </div>

    <div>
      <img src="" alt="img">
      <img src="" alt="img">
    </div>
  </div>
```

Here is [my code in codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-euclid-imr7h)

```
<template>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div
      v-for="(item, index) in homePageImageList"
      :key="index"
      class="hero-image"
      :style="{ backgroundImage: 'url(' + item.imageURL + ')' }"
    ></div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "HelloWorld",
  data() {
    return {
      homePageImageList: [
        {
          imageURL:
            "https://timeweb.com/ru/community/article/1d/1d959c23e81024374895da086675b298.jpg",
        },
        {
          imageURL:
            "https://timeweb.com/ru/community/article/1d/1d959c23e81024374895da086675b298.jpg",
        },
        {
          imageURL:
            "https://timeweb.com/ru/community/article/1d/1d959c23e81024374895da086675b298.jpg",
        },
        {
          imageURL:
            "https://timeweb.com/ru/community/article/1d/1d959c23e81024374895da086675b298.jpg",
        },
      ],
    };
  },
};
</script>

<style scoped>
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.hero-image {
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  max-width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid white;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
}
</style>
```

I think there is no need for a detailed description here everything is clear, I have four objects that store a link to a picture, then I display them using v-for

Comment: If data is static, you can divide them into subarrays yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `slice()` method to divide the array in chunks.

```
<template>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div
            v-for="chunk in Math.ceil(homePageImageList.length / 2)"
            :key="'chunk-'+chunk"
            class="hero-image"
        >
            <img :src="item.imageURL" alt="img" :key="'img-'+index" v-for="(item, index) in homePageImageList.slice((chunk - 1) * 2, chunk * 2)">
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

Comment: That's actually really creative, i wonder how well this will go with larger dataset